# RequireJS Undefined Module

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am loading JQuery and JQuery UI. For some reason JQueryUI is undefined and I cannot seem to figure out why. I know the path is correct because if I change it to an incorrect one I get a different error, so I know it is "loading" it but I cannot figure out why it is undefined. I have loaded many other modules just fine, so I don't know what the problem is. I don't see how I would be including a circular dependency, which is the only thing I have seem to found that would cause this. Thank you for any help.

Main.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'text': '../../Scripts/RequireJS/text',     
        'jquery': "../../Scripts/JQuery/jquery-2.1.1",
        'JQueryUI': "../../Scripts/JQueryUI/jquery-ui.min",      
        'app': 'app'
    },
    shim: {
        'app': {
            deps: [ 'kendovendor']
        },
       'JQueryUI': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});
```

Then I try to load it in a view model:

```
define(['JQueryUI', 'jquery'], function (jqui, jq) {
    //jqui is undefined, jq is not.
    ...
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use jquery ui with requirejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113172/how-do-i-use-jquery-ui-with-requirejs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery UI is built on top of the jQuery. I don't think you can directly call its members. Try to call some of JUI functions (for example *$(..some input button.. ).button()* ) and it should work. Defining your module like this should be sufficient:

```
define([ 
'jquery',
'JQueryUI'
], function (jq) 
{
//jq(..).button();
}
```

Comment: Yes, first he needs to load jquery an map it to the first parameter and than UI. Don't map UI to any parameter.

Comment: The only thing I can't figure out is why my #tabs aren't changing after the function runs. I know it is getting the object. It works when I have the code on the homepage, so I know it has something to do with RequireJS again.

Comment: You're welcome :) So I assume you're using jui tabs. I think we would need to see some code to help you figure out the issue.

Comment: I fixed it. I changed the name of my div from tabs to something else. Dunno what else was affecting it. Thanks again!